# Keyboard Shortcut to change pasted date in number format into TEXT

Tags: microsoft-word

Does anyone know how to change a date from number format into text format in Microsoft Word?

For example, if I type (or paste) the date 03/07/1992 - is there a keyboard shortcut to change it to March 7, 1992?

I've been searching forever and I cannot seem to find an answer.

Note that I don't need to know the keyboard shortcut to insert the current date. I'm talking about random dates that I'm pasting from an application into a Microsoft Word document.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a format of inserted date in MS Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/869458/how-to-change-a-format-of-inserted-date-in-ms-word)

Answer (score 0):

### There is no straightforward way to do this without field or vba coding.

That is, there is no built-in keyboard shortcut, nor a Word command to which a keyboard shortcut could be attached.

See my page on [Date Fields in Microsoft Word](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart).

The following field would do what you want:

```
{ Quote "[Pasted Content]" \@ "MMMM d, yyyy" }
```

The quotation marks are required. [Pasted Content] represents what you are pasting.

You could make such a field an [AutoText](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm) entry and attach a [keyboard shortcut](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) to it. Then you would need to edit the field to paste your content.

This seems more trouble than just typing what you want. If you want, it might be possible to write a macro to do this. A [keyboard shortcut](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) for a macro can also be created. A macro could also do the conversion without using a field and simply insert the text.

### Here is a macro that would do what you want.

It relies on [code found on the Microsoft site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard) to get the pasted data.

```
Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As _
   Long) As Long
Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags&, ByVal _
   dwBytes As Long) As Long
Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
   ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
 
Public Const GHND = &H42
Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096

Function ClipBoard_GetData()
    '   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard
   Dim hClipMemory As Long
   Dim lpClipMemory As Long
   Dim MyString As String
   Dim RetVal As Long
'   Dim CF_TEXT As String
 
   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open Clipboard. Another app. may have it open"
      Exit Function
   End If
          
   ' Obtain the handle to the global memory
   ' block that is referencing the text.
   hClipMemory = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
   If IsNull(hClipMemory) Then
      MsgBox "Could not allocate memory"
      GoTo OutOfHere
   End If
 
   ' Lock Clipboard memory so we can reference
   ' the actual data string.
   lpClipMemory = GlobalLock(hClipMemory)
 
   If Not IsNull(lpClipMemory) Then
      MyString = Space$(MAXSIZE)
      RetVal = lstrcpy(MyString, lpClipMemory)
      RetVal = GlobalUnlock(hClipMemory)
       
      ' Peel off the null terminating character.
      MyString = Mid(MyString, 1, InStr(1, MyString, Chr$(0), 0) - 1)
   Else
      MsgBox "Could not lock memory to copy string from."
   End If
 
OutOfHere:
 
   RetVal = CloseClipboard()
   ClipBoard_GetData = MyString
 
End Function
```

The code above is from the Microsoft site.

The macro is:

```
Sub DatePasteFormatted()
    ' Charles Kenyon 9 March 2022
    ' requires code from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard
    Dim strPaste As String
    Let strPaste = ClipBoard_GetData
    Let strPaste = Format(strPaste, "MMMM d, yyyy")
    Selection.TypeText strPaste
End Sub
```

This does not check to make sure what is in the clipboard as a date but it should work with any date. All of the code needs to go in the same standard vba module.

Here is a [link on how to use macros found on a forum](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by Word MVP Graham Mayor.

Here is a [link to a template that contains the macros](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk9kjsmvrmz728g/PasteFormattedDate.dotm?dl=0). You may have trouble downloading a macro-enabled template. Here is the [same in a zip folder](https://www.dropbox.com/s/laqd5ldnc2byl7s/PasteFormattedDate%20%282%29.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Hey thank you for taking the time to answer. Your answer offered a little bit more direction than what I had. RE: that a.) short answer there is no existing keyboard shortcut for what I want. and b.) that I would need to create a Macro or an AutoText entry.  I was looking into Macro's last night and was able to teach myself how do to a simple Macro & assigning a shortcut. (basically, if i select CTRL, L, L - my Word doc will insert an often repeated City, County, State that I usually type in.)  I'm super in the dark as far as this stuff goes - here as a learner. TYSM!

Comment: For oft-repeated things, use AutoText or another Building Block, not a macro. Here is my page on these features. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm

Comment: Will check it out, thank you!

Comment: See modified answer. I created a template with the macros and added links to it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers